# Using a registered variable in ansible after removing single quotes

Tags: ansible

After registering the result of a task ,when i debug the variable. The value i get is in double quotes like `"1234"`. If i use in another module or ansible task it becomes `[u'1234']`.

I have removed character u and brackets using replace.

How to get rid of single quotes which is ansible default.

```
Actual output : '1234'
expected output: 1234
```

Playbook snippet

```
 - uri:
      url: http://test/ws?Id=4a3d
      method: GET
      content_as_json: yes
      password: admin
      user: admin
      validate_certs: no
      return_content: yes
      HEADER_Cookie: "{{login.set_cookie}}"
     register: name

- debug: msg="{{ name.content | regex_findall('name=\"(\d+)\"') }}"
     register: test    

   - uri:
      url: "http://test/ws?name={{test.msg | replace('u','') | replace('[','') | replace(']','')}}"
      method: GET
      content_as_json: true
      password: admin
      user: admin
      validate_certs: no
      return_content: yes
      HEADER_Cookie: "{{login.set_cookie}}"
```

I used `int` also but that returned 0.

```
{{test.msg | replace('u','') | replace('[','') | replace(']','') | int}}
```

URI module output:

```
"<listResponse type=\"cust\" count=\"1\"><instance name=\"1234\" id=\"abcd\" customerRefId=\"xyz\" refId1=\"2345\" type=\"org\" enabled=\"true\" phone=\"\" fax=\"\" billingZip=\"\" billingAddress=\"\" billingCity=\"\" billingCountry=\"\" billingState=\"\" vendorId=\"1\" defaultEmail=\"pqr\" defaultContactName=\"wer\"/></listResponse>"
```

Comment: Please add your playbook snippet. I suspect there's a better way to go.

Comment: Added the code snippet

Comment: Why do you use debug here? Just feed `regex_findall` into url of the next task.

Comment: If i don't use debug it gives template error. Infact in debug module also if i  use ':' instead of equal to it fails. Though i have used list format in my complete playbook

Comment: Add content example to the question, please.

Comment: I have updated the question with dummy content which shows the format in which it is generated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `debug` action and use filtered name with next task:

```
  - uri:
      url: "http://test/ws?name={{ name.content | regex_search('name=\"(\\d+)\"','\\1') | first }}"
      method: GET
      content_as_json: true
      password: admin
      user: admin
      validate_certs: no
      return_content: yes
      HEADER_Cookie: "{{login.set_cookie}}"
```

In this case `regex_search('name=\"(\d+)\"','\1')` searches for `name=\"<number>\"` and prints only number (as it is the first matched group – second parameter for regex_search).

Comment: Syntax error with this solution at "(\d+)\" pointing to first slash.If i remove the outer double quotes then i get the same "[u'1234']" as the response for name

Comment: @DeepaliMittal sorry, corrected the code: escape slashes and fetch first element.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked and its so amazing i had tried so many things regex and backslash but could not get it working.

Comment: One more thing if my content is changed to "<endDate>2019-07-31</endDate>" and i want to get the date. What would be the reg expression if i use debug ?

Answer (score 0):

Register output in variable and use `{{var.stdout}}` to get the result. It will `1234` without any more characters.

```
- shell: echo 1234
  register: out

- debug: msg="Output= {{out.stdout}}"
```

Comment: I am registering the output. But it is webservices response in JSON and XML format. From that I am fetching the value and passing to next task

Comment: `- debug: msg="{{ name.content }}` will return your data without any `u` or `' '`. Have you tried to pass `{{ name.content }}` to next task?

Comment: I can not directly use name.context,it has a lot other data as well in XML format. Look above i have added what is their in content